# Is it okay to call another endpoint inside the then() function? ReactJS Axios

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, axios

I'm new in React js and I have question regarding the my endpoint.
Is it okay to call another endpoint inside the .then() function?
Here is my code:

```
this.props.getReviwerSurvey(surveyId, authToken.id)
  .then(
    () => {
      const {
        reviewerSurvey } = this.state;
      this.props.getAccount(reviewerSurvey && reviewerSurvey.relationships ?
      reviewerSurvey.relationships.participant.id : null);

    },
  );
```

this.props.getReviewerSurvey is my first endpoint and my second endpoint this.props.getAccount() It seems that it is not standard. How can i get the values for reviewerSurvey.relationships.participant.id without calling the this.props.getAccount inside the callback? If there is another way. Ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the resolved promise from the first request and pass it to the next `then` chain, this way you will avoid the callback hell.

Some general example:

```
this.props.getReviwerSurvey(surveyId, authToken.id)
  .then(() => {
      const { reviewerSurvey } = this.state;
      return reviewerSurvey;
    },
  ).then((reviewerSurvey) => {
     return this.props.getAccount(reviewerSurvey && reviewerSurvey.relationships ?
      reviewerSurvey.relationships.participant.id : null);
  }).then((participantId) => {
      // do something with participantId or other data related to the account
  });
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this idea. Thanks!